# Partially ordered set and injection functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could you please help me understand how to deal with this question ?

Suppose $<A,\prec>$ is partially ordered set and $f(x)=${$a\in A|a\prec x$} is a function. Prove that $f$ is not injection function: there are $y \neq z \in A$ such as $f(y)=f(z)$.

While I can pretty easily prove this statement for a specific partially ordered set,
I somehow cannot find a formal prove that will be valid for any partially ordered set.

Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't look true to me.

Comment: any well ordered set is partially ordered, yet such a mapping is injective. If I get this right the mapping is $A\to\mathcal P(A), x\mapsto \{a< x\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function collects elements *strictly* greater than the given element (so $f(a)$ doe not contain $a$) your function *can* not be injective over some set; for example, consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,6\}$ and the divisibility relation $\mid$. You can see that $f(2)=f(3)=\{6\}$.

However, it may be one-to-one over another set; the easiest example is the singleton with the trivial ordering. More complicated example is any linearly ordered set.

If $f(a)$ contains $a$, then $f$ is injective; if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a\in f(b)$ and $b\in f(a)$, so $a\le b$ and $b\le a$.

Comment: Maybe this is an answer than my professor had wanted: if A is a partly ordered set than we cannot say that for any set A function f is ingective.